# Remember me checkbox is not visible in the params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am implementing the **Remember me** option for the sign-in page. The form takes email, password and the **Remember me** checkbox. Here is the simple code for the form.

```
%header
= flash[:alert]
%h1 Sign In
= form_tag signin_path do
    -# fieldset draw a box around the form elements
    %fieldset
        %p
            = label_tag 'email'
            = email_field_tag :email
        %p
            = label_tag 'password'
            = password_field_tag :password

        %p
            = label_tag :remember_me
            = check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, params[:remember_me]
        %p
            = submit_tag 'Sign In'
```

The code works just fine. I can see :email and :password in the params hash but not :remember_me. I am inspecting the params hash by inserting a fail statement in Sessions#create.

What could be the reason?

Comment: What when you check the "Remember me"? I think you must to getting it in params in this case

Comment: Yup if it's not ticked it doesn't come at all, rather than coming through as false. If it's ticked it should be in the params hash though?

Comment: I ticked the checkbox and now I see it in the params hash.

Answer (score 0):

Use `check_box` method. It adds hidden field to the form and pass it as a params even if it's not checked.